# me/home graph api not returning open graph actions shown in news feed

Tags: facebook-opengraph, feed

I have defined custom open graph action and objects in my facebook app, and I can see the shared open graph actions in my facebook's news feed webpage.  However, when I do a me/home graph api call, I can get everything in the news feed except for the shared open graph actions. Anyone knows if open graph actions/objects are available through me/home?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses factors such as your app's popularity, spam rates, click rates, quality of images on the objects and possibly more to determine how to render an action in the newsfeed - or how not to render it. Your actions are more likely to show up on the news feed as your app grows more popular.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/distribution:

> Note: we consider various factors such as image quality, spam rates, and click rates when determining how the story is rendered, so you may not see the story show up in your News Feed when testing.